# Can "Digital Signature of the Block by the Miner" be used in place of "Nonce"?

Tags: blockchain, nonce

As it is understood that arriving nonce is very resource intensive, whether "Digital Signature of the Block by the Miner" can be considered in place of "Nonce"? Its Shortcomings, if not suitable.

Comment: You seem to be confused about what the nonce actually achieves. The nonce allows miners to "rehash" the same block multiple times, eventually finding a sufficiently "difficult" block that they can publish and be rewarded for. The nonce is either picked randomly or incremented. This is much faster than a digital signature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This only raises the question of which miners' signatures are considered acceptable.  If anyone can be a miner and provide a signature, then there is no security and no way to objectively determine which of many conflicting blocks is authoritative.  If there is a fixed list of authorized public keys, then the currency is no longer decentralized.

Comment: It took your answer for me to understand what the question was. Could you perhaps edit the question?